# how to get a data from /firebase/user/userid/items/itemid/itemsData

Tags: java, android-recyclerview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1qvs.png)

`database structure
/firestore-database
/users
- test1
- items
- milk
- coke
- test2
- items
- milk
- coke
- coffee

i could run the code no problem but when i go to the StockScreen it kicks me out and put me to the last visited Sreen/Page`

```
public class StockScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "StockScreen";
    private ArrayList<Item> itemList;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private recyclerAdapter adapter;
    private FirebaseFirestore db;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stock_screen);

        itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewItems);

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        setRecyclerView();

        retrieveItemsForUser();

    }

    private void retrieveItemsForUser() {
        FirebaseUser currentUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
        String userId = currentUser.getUid();
        db.collection("users")
                .document(userId)
                .collection("items")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                                String itemName = document.getString("itemName");
                                double listPrice = document.getDouble("listPrice");
                                double retailPrice = document.getDouble("retailPrice");
                                int stockQty = Objects.requireNonNull(document.getLong("stockQty")).intValue();
                                int soldQty = Objects.requireNonNull(document.getLong("soldQty")).intValue();

                                itemList.add(new Item(itemName, listPrice, retailPrice, stockQty, soldQty));

                            }
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(StockScreen.this,"error cant get any data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void setRecyclerView() {
        adapter = new recyclerAdapter(itemList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

`the expected output would show the data in RecyclerView
i already have a login function so i want to get its data on who login

1. user = test1
   -item name = milo
   -list price = 90
   -etc.......
2. user = test2
   -item name = Coke
   -list price = 20
   -etc......

   -item name = Milk
   -list price = 100
   etc........``